# How to set up Canon MX 855 Wireless connection?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, printer

I have an wireless printer "Canon MX 855". I can print wit it when I have a LAN-Cable connection. Today I bought a notebook (with Windows 7) and tried to connect to the printer over a wireless connection but Windows 7 doesn´t support the printer. Are there any special drivers for Windows 7?
But more important: **How can I connect to the printer over a wireless connection with Windows 7?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find a Canon MX855.

If your printer is a Pixma MX885, Win7 drivers are available from [this Canon site](http://www.canon.com.au/Home-Office/Printers/PIXMA-InkJet-Printers/MX885). Manuals are available from the same link.

For wireless setup, watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sotHO4Rt6nE) or have a look at [this document](https://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MX_series/PIXMA_MX885.aspx?faqtcmuri=tcm:13-817895&page=1&type=faq)